# Why close and not migrate?

Tags: discussion, migration

For example my [HTC HD2 How to switch between apps?](https://superuser.com/questions/234687/htc-hd2-how-to-switch-between-apps) was closed and not migrated. I think it was a right choice:

> Questions on Super User are expected
>   to generally relate to computer
>   software or computer hardware in some
>   way, within the scope defined in the
>   faq.

In the FAQ it says that smartphones do not use computer software or computer hardware and that is ok, but why this question was not migrated to another SE site?

What can I do to migrate it? (It does have a one very good comment.) Or should I forget about it and ask it again on another site?

Comment: The *exact* same question was asked on the android.se  http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4862/htc-hd2-how-to-switch-between-apps

Comment: Please click the link to the FAQ in that close message. Also: it's your own responsibility to adhere to the rules; migration is just an additional service.

Comment: Oh yeah: The HD2 isn't an Android device, so it's off-topic for Android as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What can I do to migrate it?(it does have a one very good comment) or should the poor guy forget about it and ask it again on another site?

You could

- Drop a comment mentioning it is offtopic & direct him to the relevant Stack Exchange site ( if it exists)
- Flag it for moderator attention with a request for migrating to relevant Stack Exchange site. ♦ mods can migrate to (any ?) Stack Exchange 2.0 site.

Comment: The moderator would have to decide if there was a suitable site, but this is the correct workflow. The target can be any site - including metas - but the moderator may not agree with you.

Comment: good to know, thx.

Answer (score 5):

Closed questions are migrated when:

- A sister site exists that considers the questions as on topic
- The question is detailed enough for a moderator to determine where it belongs

Your question didn't meet the criteria for Super User, which by now you should know. Secondly, you gave no indication in the question of what OS the phone is running, apart from the name of the phone.

Since I couldn't determine if I need to migrate the question, I simply closed it as off topic, until such time as someone flags it for a valid site.

**Tip** *Review the FAQ of every site before posting questions.*

Comment: Closing it was a good choice. Thanks for keeping things tidy!

Comment: thx for answer, I just remember there was this Gadgets site, but i could not remember name for it. Does putting "windows mobile" on that question would have changed anything?

Comment: @01 No it would not have changed a thing. It is still off topic for Super User.

Answer (score 3):

There is no migration path to any smartphone\smart-device related SE site. You could propose one.

Comment: There was [Gadgets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/pruning-season/), which failed to take off for various reasons.

Comment: @Yi Jiang: Wait, so we don't have such a SE site?

Comment: Gadgets had too much overlap with Apple and Android, and didn't gained traction, so the team decided to shut it down.

Comment: @Yi Jiang thx, I knew there was some site for this, but I couldn't find it.